# How to make watch display its output at the center of the screen?

Tags: watch-command

Every time I use the watch command in the terminal the output is displayed from the screen start and it seems a bit awkward. I am hoping to make watch display the output at the screen center.

```
$ watch -n 1 du -hs "*.part"

52K     Prince of Tennis Episode 100 English Subbed Online - Chia-Anime.mp4.part
64M     Prince of Tennis Episode 92 English Subbed Online - Chia-Anime.mp4.part
53M     Prince of Tennis Episode 93 English Subbed Online - Chia-Anime.mp4.part
23M     Prince of Tennis Episode 94 English Subbed Online - Chia-Anime.mp4.part
13M     Prince of Tennis Episode 95 English Subbed Online - Chia-Anime.mp4.part
24K     Prince of Tennis Episode 96 English Subbed Online - Chia-Anime.mp4.part
12K     Prince of Tennis Episode 97 English Subbed Online - Chia-Anime.mp4.part
40K     Prince of Tennis Episode 98 English Subbed Online - Chia-Anime.mp4.part
36K     Prince of Tennis Episode 99 English Subbed Online - Chia-Anime.mp4.part
```

I want this output to start appearing from the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `watch` and `printf` to produce your desired output.

Here is an example script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
columns="$(tput cols)"
du -hs *.part | while read i; do
   printf "%*s\n" $(( (${#i} + columns) / 2)) "$i"
done
```

Save it with a name like `script.sh` and run it like:

```
watch bash script.sh
```

the output would be:

```
                            4.0K    myfile
                            4.0K    anotherfile
                        54M coreutils-8.25
            28K coreutils_8.25-2ubuntu2.debian.tar.xz
                 4.0K   coreutils_8.25-2ubuntu2.dsc
                 5.5M   coreutils_8.25.orig.tar.xz
```

Here is an other script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.part
do
 title=`du -hs "$i"`
 echo -e "\t\t\t\t$title\n"
done
```

run it:

```
watch bash myscript.sh
```

it's going to show you a result look like:

```
                    4.0K    myfile

                    4.0K    anotherfile

                    54M     coreutils-8.25

                    28K     coreutils_8.25-2ubuntu2.debian.tar.xz

                    4.0K    coreutils_8.25-2ubuntu2.dsc

                    5.5M    coreutils_8.25.orig.tar.xz
```

Use as many `\t` you need to get your desired result.

Comment: Why does it move the result to that position as you added `''` and I am curious and I can't seem to get mine to print `foo` rather i see `tfoo`

Comment: You sure about it? for the third command it should print  `foo`, the manual doesn't seem to say anything useful however it suggest to test some quoting, that was how I found about it ...

Comment: Linux ever impresses me always some given _dragon_ thanks never knew much about `watch` will practice using it :)

Comment: sorry for the late edit, but believe the printf can not be used for the above example.

Comment: @devilz see my update.

Comment: to make sure a certain file type is shown, add it after * for example in the line for i in *(replace the * with *.part)